# Are onComplete/onCancel guaranteed to be called with grpc?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm supposed to execute some code at the beginning and at the end of every calls processed by my grpc server.

I use a ServerCall.Listener:

- the code to execute at the beginning of the call is located in the constructor of the listener
- the code to execute at the end of the call is triggered by onComplete and onCancel
- the thread instantiating the listener must be the one that will call onComplete / onCancel (we are using thread local variables)

The listener is instantiated by an interceptor that is registered to my server.

But there is an issue: it looks like sometimes, even if the listener has been instantiated, it is not followed by a call to onComplete nor onCancel.

To be totally accurate, the issue might also be triggered if another thread than the one instantiating the listener is calling onComplete / onCancel.

Is one of those situations supposed to happen ? I'm using grpc-netty version 1.6.1.

Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is guaranteed that exactly one of onComplete / onCancel will be called.

The problem is "the thread instantiating the listener must be the one that will call onComplete / onCancel". This is generally not true for multiple reasons:

1. The listener creation occurs on the sending thread whereas callbacks are on a separate receiving thread.
2. The receiving thread is not a dedicated thread: it is shared and can change from callback to callback.

The Listener doesn't need to be thread-safe, but should be thread-compatible. Your current implementation [is thread-hostile](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09263/).

The only time your assumption would hold today is when using the blocking stub. But that's because of an implementation detail that you should not rely on.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric, this helps a lot !

Comment: @Eric I couldn't find on the repo any documentation regarding the threading model of the java gRPC server. Is there a resource that could be read on this?

Comment: Both StreamObserver and ClientCall/ServerCall are not thread-safe (except for methods explicitly mentioning it). That is in the Javadoc. The Listeners are independently non-thread-safe from the Calls (incoming and outgoing are independently non-thread-safe; so they can be called concurrently). StreamObserver does the best of pointing that out in the documentation.